# Ansible Yum Module pending transactions error

Tags: ansible, yum

I'm very new to Ansible. 
I am trying to follow a tutorial on the concept of Roles in Ansible.
I have the following Master Playbook:

```
--- # Master Playbook for Webservers
- hosts: apacheweb
  user: test
  sudo: yes
  connection: ssh
  roles:
    - webservers
```

Which refers to the *webservers* role that has the following *task/main.yml*:

```
- name: Install Apache Web Server
  yum: pkg=httpd state=latest
  notify: Restart HTTPD
```

And a *handler/main.yml*:

```
- name: Restart HTTPD
  service: name=httpd state=started
```

When I execute the Master Playbook, mentioned above, I get the following error:

```
TASK [webservers : Install Apache Web Server] **********************************
fatal: [test.server.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "The following packages have pending transactions: httpd-x86_64", "rc": 128, "results": ["The following packages have pending transactions: httpd-x86_64"]}
```

I cannot understand what this error corresponds to. There does not seem to be anything similar, based on my research, that could suggest the issue with the way I am using the Yum module.

NOTE: Ansible Version:

```
ansible 2.2.1.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It seems there are unfinished / pending transactions on the target host.
Try installing `yum-utils` package to run `yum-complete-transaction` to the target hosts giving the error.

```
# yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only
```

Look at [Fixing There are unfinished transactions](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/12/01/fixing-there-are-unfinished-transactions-remaining-you-might-consider-running-yum-complete-transaction-first-to-finish-them-in-centos/) remaining for more details.

> yum-complete-transaction is a program which finds incomplete or
>   aborted yum transactions on a system and attempts to complete them. It
>   looks at the transaction-all* and transaction-done* files which can
>   normally be found in /var/lib/yum if a yum transaction aborted in the
>   middle of execution.
>
> If it finds more than one unfinished transaction it will attempt to
>   complete the most recent one first. You can run it more than once to
>   clean up all unfinished transactions.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Cheers

Comment: Also, if you have a situation where you don't have enough disk space to complete the transaction, I was able to `yum install pacakge-name` specifically as a shell task without this error.

Answer (score 1):

Unfinished transaction remaining

sudo yum install yum-utils

yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only

Comment: +1 For including the `yum install yum-utils` since the accepted answer just says yum-complete-transactions isn't a command :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using for ansible this type of config for the playbooks:

```
- name: Install Apache Web Server
  yum: name=httpd state=latest
  notify: Restart HTTPD
```

As far as i know there is no such option as `yum: pkg=httpd` in ansbile for the yum module (if I'm not wrong, that **pkg=httpd** is for apt-get on debian based distros)

If you need to install multiple packages you could use something like:

```
- name: "Install httpd packages"
  yum: name={{ item }} state=present
  with_items:
    - httpd
    - httpd-devel
    - httpd-tools
```

Of course you can change the **state=present** to **state=latest** or whatever option might suits you best

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_module.html - ansible documentation for yum module

Comment: Thanks, I see. I changed the *pkg* to *name* but I still get the same error: **The following packages have pending transactions: httpd-x86_64", "rc**

Comment: Manually execute on a ssh shell: yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only. You won't be able to use ansible to install packages until you finish your packages issues (like the uncomplete installed packages)